# Trouble overiding function of derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I'm having some trouble calling overridden functions with my AVL tree.  It's calling the one from the BST tree.  This is a bit more confusing than usual because AVLNode is derived from BinaryNode.  I needed to add a height data member.  Could that be causing the problem or is it simpler than that.

```
class BST
{
     public:
     Parent():root(NULL) { }
     void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, int& count )
     {
           insert(x, lineNum, root, count);
     }

     protected:
     BinaryNode* root;
     void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, Node * & t, int& count )
     {//stuff
     }
};

class AVL:public BST
{
     public:
     void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, int& count )
     {
        cout << "INSERT\n";   
        insert(x, lineNum, root, count);
     }
     protected:
     AVLNode* root;

     void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, AVLNode * & t, int& count )
     {
          cout << "insert\n";   
        //different stuff
     }
};

class BinaryNode
{//constructors
}

class AVLNode:public BinaryNode
{//constructors
};
```

Comment: How are you creating the AVL tree and how are you calling the methods?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the functions you want to override virtual. For instance:

```
 virtual void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, int& count )
 {
       insert(x, lineNum, root, count);
 }

 virtual void insert( const string & x, int lineNum, Node * & t, int& count )
 {//stuff
 }
```

The insert method with AVLNode* will not override the method with Node*. It will create a new overload of the insert method instead.

Also, just to be clear, there's no reason to pass pointers in by reference unless you intend to change the value of the pointer (not the pointed at) in the function and want the change to be visible in the caller. Passing by reference will just add an unnecessary dereference (subject to the aforementioned caveat).

Comment: Adding virtual seems to have fixed some of the problems.  It fixed insert, but when I'm still having problems with functions that override and return AVLNodes instead of BSTNodes.  Is this not possible?

Comment: If the only thing you're trying to change is the return type, you'll probably get an error (I do). If you are changing anything in the parameters (like the example you gave Node->AVLNode) it will overload instead of override.